# 2D openGL engine simple lightsources and framebuffers (c++)

Tags: c++, opengl, shader, framebuffer

I'm currently trying to learn openGL and I'm sort of stuck making a very easy lighting engine for my application. It's 2D and most sources I find only cover rather complicated 3D operations. What I want to do is something as simple as what is covered in this tutorial: http://www.alcove-games.com/opengl-es-2-tutorials/lightmap-shader-fire-effect-glsl/

It nudged me in the right direction and I am to understand that I'm to use a framebuffer with sort of a "light map" that I send to my shaders along with the texture I'm rendering so I can combine these values to create a lighting effect. First things first: I can't get my framebuffer to work!

I followed the following tutorial: http://open.gl/framebuffers which was neat enough. It lead me to the following code for very simply creating a framebuffer:

```
GLuint frameBuffer;
glGenFramebuffers(1, &frameBuffer);

glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, frameBuffer);
glFramebufferTexture2D(
GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, GL_TEXTURE_2D, myTexture2.texture_id, 0);
```

here myTexture2 is my texture class and the texture_id is the GLuint for this texture. (I can render this to the screen easily enough using the default frame buffer and it displays fine so I know this works). After I do this, I run the test to check if everything is fine (as the tutorial mentions):

```
    GLenum check_framebuffer = glCheckFramebufferStatus(frameBuffer);
    if (check_framebuffer == GL_FRAMEBUFFER_COMPLETE)
    {
        std::cout << "Everything is fine\n";
    }
    else{
        std::cout << "glCheckFramebufferStatus returned: " << glCheckFramebufferStatus(frameBuffer) << std::endl;
        std::cout << "GlError: " << glGetError() << std::endl;
    }
```

glCheckFramebufferStatus returns 0, with the GLerror 1280 (invalid enum?).

Nonsurprisingly, if I bind to this framebuffer before drawing, everything is just black (with the glClearColor set to red, so at the very least if it was working it should be red). If I set it back to

```
glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, 0);
```

Then everything runs fine. What is wrong with my framebuffer? I've been searching everywhere for a simple project example that I could just copypaste and run to see that it works but it's either the wrong language or uses some library I'm not intending to. Furthermore, I'm not entirely certain I'm understanding how the framebuffer works. I'm understanding that it's just another screen to draw to (or as I understand, adding another step in the rendering process?).

Currently I'm drawing everything by binding a texture, drawing a quad with the texture size, then moving on to the next texture. This means that for every single image in my application, they all run one shader each (or should I say, copies of the exact same shader currently). Am I to understand that if I have for example 20 different images running 20 shaders on screen first, I can then run these through an extra "step" to mix them with the light map I create in the framebuffer, or am I mistaken?

Sorry if these questions sound dumb, but I've been browsing through tons of tutorials right now and each one is raising more questions than it seems to answer, I generally learn best by experimenting but when I can't even get my framebuffer going, I'm sort of stuck!

Comment: What's the state of your texture going into this? Have you made a call to `TexImage2D` to establish its size and format?

Comment: Yes that's how I make my textures. The size (width and height) are stored in my texture class.

Comment: ... have you checked that you are getting a context for an OpenGL version of 3.2 or higher? That's when `glFramebufferTexture` arrived.

Comment: Try calling glGetError() before creating the framebuffer object and see if everything is okay, it may be a stale error. One big tip for programming with opengl: create a function that calls glGetError() and if there is an error, logs its enum name (ex. GL_INVALID_ENUM), the description of the error from the API, and \_\_FILE\_\_ and \_\_LINE\_\_. Then add that function call after EVERY gl* function call. Makes debugging a breeze. I wrap mine in a debug macro that is only compiled if a debug flag is defined.

Comment: Running glGetError() before testing the frame buffer returns 0, after returns 1280. And for Tommy, I am infact not using openGL version 3.2 or higher, I'm using 3.1! Didn't see that mentioned anywhere. On that note, attempting to change my context from 3.2 to 3.1 my openGL will no longer initialize. Egad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The arguments in this call are not correct:

```
GLenum check_framebuffer = glCheckFramebufferStatus(frameBuffer);
```

The argument for this call is not a framebuffer id (name), but the framebuffer target. This should be:

```
glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, frameBuffer);
GLenum check_framebuffer = glCheckFramebufferStatus(GL_FRAMEBUFFER);
```

If you use this call, it should give you more details about why the actual rendering is failing. The `glFramebufferTexture2D()` call looks basically ok. So it most likely is related to how the texture is set up, which is not shown in the posted code.

Comment: Well what do you know. That's so typical of me, it was working all along. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The name for framebuffer object technology in DirectX is "render to texture". So it's not "another screen to draw to"; it's an OFFLINE texture.

Some key concepts:

1. The data is stored in the texture. FBO (framebuffer object) is just to tell OpenGL how to render to this texture.
2. There's only one "on-screen" object, which is the back buffer. All the other "render target" (AKA FBO in OpenGL) are offline. You have to draw to the back buffer, if you want to show something on the screen.

The basic steps to use FBO is:

1. Create a texture
2. Create an FBO; bind the texture to FBO; bind the FBO as "render target"
3. Draw to the FBO
4. Switch back to the back buffer (`glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, 0);`)
5. Bind the texture as "texture"
6. Draw something to the back buffer, and you can sample the texture now

You can refer to http://www.songho.ca/opengl/gl_fbo.html for detailed code sample.

Comment: Thanks for clearing that up. I've already looked a bit at that example, and I still can't understand why glCheckFramebufferStatus returns 0.